# Why isn't this simple jQuery working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"/>
$(document).ready({
   $(".title").click(function(){
      var descID = $(this).attr("id");
      var newID = "#"+descID+"d";
      $(newID).slideToggle('slow');
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<span id="3" class="title">title</span>
<span id="3d" class="description">description</span>
```

CSS:

```
.description {
    display: none;
}
```

Not a jQuery/javascript expert. What am I missing? I'm trying to get the appropriate `description` to slide toggle while clicking on the proper `title`. Right now I don't see anything happen.

Comment: Haha, yup typo. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Is that really exactly what your HTML looks like, with that self-closing `<script>` tag immediately followed by the JavaScript code?

Comment: @Pointy no, I just wanted to include that in case I was missing something. I'll try changing the `id` values so they start with letters.

Comment: I think ebaxt's answer is a big part of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a fair number of errors.  Corrected and documented inline.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script> <!-- script tags shouldn't self close, non-standard -->
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- open script tag for inline scripts -->
$(document).ready(function() { <!-- need function definition for ready event handler
   $(".title").click(function(){
      var descID = $(this).attr("id");
      var newID = "#"+descID+"d";
      $(newID).slideToggle('slow');
   });
});
</script> <!-- end script tag -->
```

Comment: What was messing up my page was forgetting the `</script>` and self-closing the script tag instead. Thanks for this.

Comment: The jQuery script tag was closed right? with the '/>'. The other script tag was indeed missing. Good spotting :)

Comment: @PoweRoy some browsers won't process a self-closing script tag.  The standard, both HTML 4 and 5, indicate that a closing `</script>` tag is required.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a function after: $(document).ready(

Should be:

```
<html>
<head>
...
    <style type="text/css">
        .description {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<span id="3" class="title">title</span>
<span id="3d" class="description">description</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".title").click(function () {
            var descID = $(this).attr("id");
            var newID = "#" + descID + "d";
            $(newID).slideToggle('slow');
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added `function()` and I still don't see anything happening when I click on the `title`. I also changed my `id`s so that they start with a letter instead of a number.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `function()` part. And a opening and closing script tag, as others pointed out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function(){
       $(".title").click(function(){
          var descID = $(this).attr("id");
          var newID = "#"+descID+"d";
          $(newID).slideToggle('slow');
       });
    });
</script>
```

Test your site here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tSQqx/)

Comment: Weird. It works perfectly in jsfiddle, but the same code doesn't work on my site. Thanks.

Comment: indeed I missed that you forgot a <script> and </script> tags around your jquery code

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function to ready, and you're passing an object-literal by accident.

You can use this to play around with the example (I love jsfiddle!)
http://jsfiddle.net/hmdrP/

There's also a shortcut, `$(function() { ... })` which is equivalent.